# Implementing __set__ in a custom list

Tags: python, list

I have implemented a custom list with many of the available magic methods (`__setitem__`, `__getitem__`, `__iter__`, `__add__`, `__iadd__`,...).

I'm wondering if there is a way to implement the assignment operator (called when I do `my_object.my_list=[some other list]`).

I've thinking abour descriptors, but I have to get the instance where the property resides (`my_object` in the example) in the other methods, so I can't just define it static and use `getattr`.

I have something like the following:

```
class List (object):
    def __init__ (self, instance):
        self._instance = instance
        self._items = []
        ...
    def __getattr__ (self, index):
        something using self._instance
        ...
    def __setattr__ (self, index, value):
        something more using self._instance even more
        ...
    ...
class ListCreator (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        ...
    def setup (self, instance, name):
        l = List(instance)
        setattr(instance,name,l)
class A (object):
    x = ListCreator()
    def __init__ (self):
        for key,value in self.__class__.__dict__:
            if isinstance(value,ListCreator):
                value.setup(self,key)
```

The issue is I want to access the list as a.x, where a is an instance of A, but I want it to behave like a list, with the other methods implemented. But, if I define the `ListCreator` instances as a descriptor and throw `List` I cannot access the `a` instance inside these methods.

Which would be the best way to do something like this? I've tried to continue using `List` such that and implementing `__set__` in the `ListCreator` class, but then I can't access the list methods.

Comment: The assignment of `myobj.mylist = [...]` is handled by `myobj`, not `mylist`.  You'll need to override `__setattr__` in `A`.

Comment: It works perfectly at least in this case.

Answer (score 1):

No; the assignment `variable = new_list` is not a behaviour of the list, and it is especially not a behaviour of whatever value was in the variable before. It will forget what the variable was referring to before, and put a new reference into it.

If you have an instance variable, as in your case, the assignment is controlled by the object the variable is on, so you can redefine it; but it has, again, nothing to do with the value it contained before.